# Parsing JSON with Argo

Tags: java, json, parsing

I'm attempting to parse the data from `http://api.randomuser.me/` and incorporate it into my Java application. The JSON data looks as follows:

```
{"results":[{"user":{"gender":"female","name":{"title":"mrs","first":"riley","last":"barnes"},"location":{"street":"6900 washington ave","city":"lousville","state":"new jersey","zip":"82561"},"email":"riley.barnes83@example.com","username":"bluebear21","password":"michaela","salt":"#nH{uwT4","md5":"854a2e76639bc59a8bc08f8f1ceadeb0","sha1":"c84ec59a9137685aec1909e16642e75aecc3221e","sha256":"4dd09f1e230d7a98ebfe2c14588fedc6d6f436eecc72952dd4565d8e51823ac4","registered":"968313341","dob":"316929409","phone":"(288)-381-2384","cell":"(804)-975-5466","SSN":"546-48-9490","picture":"http://api.randomuser.me/0.3/portraits/women/17.jpg"},"seed":"6a35aafac76ff6f","version":"0.3"}]}
```

I'm using `http://argo.sourceforge.net/` to parse the data, but i keep getting this error when attempting to.

```
Exception in thread "main" argo.jdom.JsonNodeDoesNotMatchPathElementsException: Failed to find a field called ["user"] at ["user"] while resolving ["user"] in [{"results":[{"user":{"gender":"female","name":{"title":"miss","first":"hannah","last":"parker"},"location":{"street":"4708 daisy dr","city":"waxahachie","state":"new hampshire","zip":"32151"},"email":"hannah.parker73@example.com","username":"blackswan57","password":"ellie","salt":"4IkJxhN2","md5":"40ccea4f5670f63af4c3ba26f749d735","sha1":"f9ac6e78079ff34f8bd018884bf658ac2c39d8c3","sha256":"b04fb6337fc7e5e26b096ddd3895a8e6500783fbe026f2cd92febd427df9b505","registered":"1140098652","dob":"492991640","phone":"(847)-802-9539","cell":"(816)-467-2525","SSN":"756-30-7542","picture":"http://api.randomuser.me/0.3/portraits/women/26.jpg"},"seed":"baffebbfa57c353","version":"0.3"}]}].
at argo.jdom.JsonNodeDoesNotMatchPathElementsException.jsonNodeDoesNotMatchPathElementsException(JsonNodeDoesNotMatchPathElementsException.java:23)
at argo.jdom.JsonNode.wrapExceptionsFor(JsonNode.java:359)
at argo.jdom.JsonNode.getStringValue(JsonNode.java:184)
at twitter.ciangallagher.net.RandomUserGenerator.genUser(RandomUserGenerator.java:55)
at twitter.ciangallagher.net.Browser.main(Browser.java:646)
```

The code i have written is as follows:

```
    class RandomUserGenerator {
    public String text;

    public void genUser() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException, ParseException, InvalidSyntaxException{
        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet("http://api.randomuser.me/");
        getRequest.addHeader("accept", "application/json");

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(getRequest);

        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
               + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                         new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));

        String output; // API output

        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
            text = output;
        }

        System.out.println(text);
        String secondSingle = new JdomParser().parse(text).getStringValue("user");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the worst library documentation I have ever seen in 10 years.

There are far superior libraries to parse JSON such as GSON, flexjson, jackson, etc (I myself like flexjson).

But if you want to go ahead with this one, let me show you an example of how can you get some value

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidSyntaxException {

    StringBuffer text = new StringBuffer();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(JSON.class.getResourceAsStream("json.txt")));

    String output; // API output

    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(output);
        text.append(output);
    }

    System.out.println(text);
    JsonRootNode rootNode = new JdomParser().parse(text.toString());
    List<JsonNode> results = rootNode.getArrayNode("results");
    JsonNode firstUserMap = results.get(0);
    JsonField user = firstUserMap.getFieldList().get(0);
    JsonNode userNode = user.getValue();
    JsonField name = userNode.getFieldList().get(1);
    JsonNode nameNode = name.getValue();
    JsonField firstName = nameNode.getFieldList().get(1);
    System.out.println(firstName.getValue().getText());

}
```

prints

```
riley
```

ps. snippet of the JSON

```
{
   "results":[
      {
         "user":{
            "gender":"female",
            "name":{
               "title":"mrs",
               "first":"riley",
               "last":"barnes"
            },
     (...)
```